# Android java reducing bitmap memory load

Tags: java, android, memory, bitmap

I've already asked a question about kinda the same topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34619333/android-java-out-of-memory-exception-loading-spritsheets/34619549?noredirect=1#comment56987884_34619549)), but I've got another question so I thought a new question would be better (correct me if I'm wrong).

I noticed that the Android Bitmap uses per pixel encoding. This is rather inefficient. I then stumbled on the BitmapFactory.Options class which lets you choose a smaller per pixel (RGB_565) format:

```
public BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
```

And then using this option when loading the Bitmap to reduce the memory load. But still you've got a per pixel encoding. Now my question, is there a way possible to use a non per-pixel encoding for displaying a bitmap onto a canvas? Or is it possible to upscale a smaller bitmap without costing more memory (I.e you've got a 10x10 image and want to upscale it to 100x100 withouth needing to have the 100000 pixels in memory but only the 100)?

Hope my question is clear. I could post some of my code, but I don't see the added value of this for this specific question.

Comment: Not sure if it's answered here but... check this out : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very frustrating, I've been thinking about this problem for several days, read the Bitmap documentation over and over again and eventually desperately posting a question of stackoverflow and after a few minutes after posting I figure out this solution.

The thing is that this is not an option in the Bitmap class, but in the Canvas class. The Canvas class has a couple of functions for this decribed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html):

> drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)
>
> drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)
>
> drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)

Sorry for bothering, but I'm glad I got a solution. I hope some other people may find this usefull.